# Resource to learn Intellij plugin development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to learn how create IntelliJ' plugins, but after looking at the JetBrains help, I think it's very little and doesn't help new developers.

So, where can I find a good site or help to learn IntelliJ plugins ? Is there a more complete documentation than the confluence one ?

Sincerely,

Comment: [Have you checked the intellij-plugin tag wiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/intellij-plugin/info)

Comment: http://bjorn.tipling.com/how-to-make-an-intellij-idea-plugin-in-30-minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the very basics (getting started with plugin development), there is a good number of information both on the JetBrains site (including recordings of webinars that show live-streamed plugin development) and elsewhere on the Web.

For more specific tasks, there's only the Confluence site, the javadocs and the Community Edition source code. So if you have any questions that are not covered by the existing documentation, please ask them here or at the [JetBrains plugin development forum](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions&start=0).